# Reload AsyncTask with new parameters

Tags: android, android-asynctask, parse-platform

I have an AsyncTask that loads all my data on parse.com, then the user has a checkbox to select the categories he wants to display.
Once I get those choices (from a separate class via an interface), I reload the asyncTask, but It still lists everything (like if the array of choices gets erased/reloaded).

here is my code to get the selected categories :

```
    @Override
public void onOkay(ArrayList<Integer> selected) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    if (selected.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < selected.size(); i++) {
            String categories = selectedArray[selected.get(i)];
            stringBuilder = stringBuilder.append(", " + categories);
        }
        //this is to display the content of the selectedArray : 
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected: "
        + stringBuilder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //reloading the AsyncTask class : 
        new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    }
}
```

My AsyncTask :

```
    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //timer and progressdialog...
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        list_of_articles = new ArrayList<Articles>();
        try {

            // Locate the class table named "Article" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "Article");
            query.whereWithinKilometers("Localisation_Vendeur", device_location, rayon);

            //this is the query I use : 
            query.whereContainedIn ("Category",Arrays.asList(selectedArray));
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject article : ob) {
                // Locate images in article_image column
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) article.get("label1");
                Articles map = new Articles();
                map.setArticle_label1((String) article.get("label2"));
                map.setArticle_label2((String) article.get("label3"));
                map.setArticle_category((String) article.get("Category"));
                map.setArticle_label4((String) article.get("label4"));
                map.setArticle_image(image.getUrl());
                list_of_articles.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                list_of_articles);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

How can I make that work ? Keep in mind that the query works, i've tested with an array that i filled manually and it works.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass categories that user wants to display as arguments to AsyncTask through `AsyncTask.execute(Params... params)`. They will be available in `AsyncTask.doInBackground` method as that method parameters. Use them inside `doInBackgorund` method to set your query appropriately.

```
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<List<String>, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //timer and progressdialog...
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(List<String>... params) {
        list_of_articles = new ArrayList<Articles>();
        try {

            // Locate the class table named "Article" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "Article");
            query.whereWithinKilometers("Localisation_Vendeur", device_location, rayon);

            //this is the query I use : 
            query.whereContainedIn ("Category", params[0]);
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject article : ob) {
                // Locate images in article_image column
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) article.get("label1");
                Articles map = new Articles();
                map.setArticle_label1((String) article.get("label2"));
                map.setArticle_label2((String) article.get("label3"));
                map.setArticle_category((String) article.get("Category"));
                map.setArticle_label4((String) article.get("label4"));
                map.setArticle_image(image.getUrl());
                list_of_articles.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                list_of_articles);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Then in code run AsyncTask by calling `new RemoteDataTask().execute(Arrays.asList(selectedArray))`. Make sure that `selectedArray` is updated properly before every call of AsyncTask.

Comment: `query.whereContainedIn ("Category",Arrays.asList(selectedArray));` should be `query.whereContainedIn ("Category",stringBuilder);` ? i am just thinking.

Comment: @LeXeR `whereContainedIn`requires an array of values. I used the stringbuilder to display the content of the array (just for testing, it will be removed)

Comment: check the contents of `Arrays.asList(selectedArray)`. i think its the problem.

Comment: the `execute`function does not accept my array as a parameter. can you pleasae be more specific about how to pass those parameters ?

Comment: Pass categories to `whereContainedIn` using `AsyncTask.doInBackground` parameters i.e. you can pass String array to `AsyncTask.execute(Params... params)` and get it in `AsyncTask.doInBackground`. Then use that array of strings in `whereContainedIn`.